# How to implement backward comparable webservices

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

one of our client frequently make new releases of their SOAP API. and We are not always develop against their latest WSDL. but their server handles backward compatibility very well, some of the method signatures have changed completely
on the latest WSDL definition, but their server still handles our client application which uses the classes generated from the old WSDL file

I have compared the old and new WSDL file. there is no version information. I wonder how such they implemented their SOAP service

other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849890/how-to-implement-backward-compatible-soap-webservice-java-based) on the same topic seems lack of details, a working example from GItHUB or Bitbucket would be really nice.